# rsyslog with heroku

Tags: logging, rsyslog, heroku

I'm trying to capture logs from Heroku. I have setup as suggested http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog_drains.

I'm completely new to the rsyslog, please bear with me.

1. Where do I see the logs from heroku?
2. Also, how do I configure
   rsyslog to put all the Heroku logs in something like /var/log/syslog/heroku_%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%.log ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you haven't set your rsyslogd server to get messages from heroku then probably nowhere
2. You can try the [LongTermLogRotation](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/LongTermLogRotatation) from the [sample configuration files](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Configuration_Samples)

Basically you create a rule,bind it (if you manage other logs with rsyslog) that will grab the logs from say specific hosts (heroku),format and store them in a specific location.

Comment: Doesn't the following in rsyslog.conf set the rsyslogd server to get messages from heroku, when the heroku drains are to port 514? 

$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

I thought by default rsyslog keeps the logs somewhere if the rules are not added. Let me know if I'm thinking on the wrong route.